# I copied the code from the React "Getting started" codepen and it does not render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I literally copied the code example provided by the React "Getting started" homepage and it renders a blank screen with no errors.

The code below is the same code here: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/ZpvBNJ

Unlike the codepen mine does not render anything....why?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react.js"></script>
    <script scr="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<!--______________________________________________________BEGIN APP-->

<body>
    <div id="root">
        <!-- This div's content will be managed by React. -->
    </div>
</body>
<!--______________________________________________________END APP-->

</html>
```

**App.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here are the file references that work:  https://jsfiddle.net/a1j38ctq/

Comment: It works fine even through the link that you have mentioned !!
However it's still not the proper way, so take a look at this link [create react app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#create-react-app-)

Comment: I don't want to use more dependencies than I need to for learning. I consider uneeded bloat bad for learning. I'll get to it soon enough.

Comment: Well, have you added anything new to the previous html page? It works fine with me!